# MySQL Select from last 30 days not selecting today's results

Tags: mysql

I hope my question has a very dumb solution, but I'm stuck.

I have this query to get the orders from the last 30 days grouped by date.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    (order_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    DAY(order_date)
```

This query though only includes results until yesterday, not today's. What am I doing wrong?

Useful information:

- `order_date` has a `DATETIME` format.
- I've checked and the database has orders with today's date.
- I have tried changing `CURDATE()` with `NOW`, or using `BETWEEN` with no success.

Comment: What should be the output exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    (order_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY day;
```

**Note:** In your query you were grouping by `DAY(date)`. `Day` function returns the day number in a month. So, it's likely the case that the same day of two different months aggregated together in a single slot. That's why you were missing **today's** result.

Comment: Nice catch, this query will at least fix another problem.

Comment: Worked as a charm. And thank you for the note, really helpful. In 11 minutes I'll accept your answer (it won't let me now)

Comment: You will understand it clearly if you increase the interval say 60 days. you won't get more than 31 records in your result set @Mumpo

Comment: Yep, I got it, I didn't realize that `DAY()` doesn't take into account which month or year it is. It just returns the day's index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT                                
    DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,                                
    COUNT(*) AS num                                
FROM                                
    orders                                
WHERE                                
    DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= adddate(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)                                
GROUP BY                                
    DAY(order_date);
```

Hope this helps.